# jQuery dynamic table inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-table

I'm working on a school project with JS, and I've created a form where I enter the amount of forces in a problem and (through jquery) the HTML is edited so that a number of new input rows are added after the row where I entered my number of forces.

My issue: now that these new inputs are available, I am trying to set them equal to an array so I can use those values later.  I've set up a for loop that works the same as my loop for my number of forces, and I am trying to get it to record each force through clicking the buttons in the new rows. The issue is that it is not recording.

Anyone have any ideas on how I can get these values in an array? It would be very much appreciated.

Also, if any of you know of a framework for a dynamic form or table which would make this easier.

```
function forceRecording(numofforces) {
    for(var i =0; i<numofforces; i++) {
        $('#button1').parent().parent().after("<tr><td>Force DFO " + i +":</td><td><form><input type='text' name='lengthMeasure'/></form></td><td><div class='button' id='lengthButton"+i+"'>Add!</div></td></tr>")
        $('#button2').parent().parent().after("<tr><td>Force " + i +":</td><td><form><input type='text' name='forceMeasure'/></form></td><td><div class='button' id='forceButton"+i+"'>Add!</div></td></tr>")
    }

    for(var i = 0; i < numofforces;i++) {
        $("#forceButton"+i).click(function(){
            force[i]= $('select[name=forceMeasure]').val();
        });
        $('#forceButton'+i).after("<p>"+force[i]+"</p>");  //only temporary to check if the force is actually in the variable
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use more general selectors to select all of the inputs of that you need in one event.

```
function forceRecording(numofforces){
for(var i =0; i<numofforces; i++){
    $('#somediv').after("<tr><td>Force DFO " + i +":</td><td><input type='text' id='lengthMeasure"+i+"'/></td><td><div class='button' id='lengthButton_"+i+"'>Add!</div></td></tr>")
    $('#someotherdiv').after("<tr><td>Force " + i +":</td><td><input type='text' id='forceMeasure_"+i+"'/></td><td><div class='button' id='forceButton_"+i+"'>Add!</div></td></tr>")
}
};   
$("div.button[id^='forceButton']").live("click",function(){
    var num = parseInt($(this).attr("name").split("_")[1]);
    force[num]=$('text[id=forceMeasure_'+num+']').val();
    console.log(force);
});
```

Live is a better function to use if you're generating new elements to attach events to. You only need to bind events once using live rather than every time an element is created. You also only need one form element per page. Name and ids should ideally always be unique.

Comment: To get an idea for other selectors take a look at this page: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: Sorry I really am not understand how the "ParseInt($(this).attr("name").split("_")[1])" bit is working, could you elaborate?

Comment: Inside a jquery callback "this" is the html elements that you were searching for. Wrapping it in $() allows you to use jquery functions on that element. One function is attr() which takes the name of an html attribute and will return the value of that attribute for the element. The value returned is a string. I added an underscore to your elements id on insertion in the forceRecording function. The string can then be split on the underscore character returning an array with two elements, 0 being the 'forceButton' part and 1 being the counter. ParseInt turns the latter into an integer.

Comment: I also realize I should have grabbed "id" instead of "name" in the num attr function.

Comment: You could upvote or give my answer a check mark. lol no worries. I hope I wasn't too terse.